# Puppet Could not prepare for execution: Permission denied - /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_key.pem

Tags: centos, puppet, selinux

I am trying to configure a puppet master on a CentOS 6 server with SELinux enabled.

When I try to run the puppetmaster, I get the following. I have given all the permissions but it still cannot write.

```
[root@server ssl]# puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
Info: Creating a new SSL key for ca
Error: Could not prepare for execution: Permission denied - /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_key.pem
[root@server ssl]# chmod -R 777 /var/lib/puppet/
[root@server ssl]# ls -lZ
drwxrwxrwx. puppet puppet system_u:object_r:puppet_var_lib_t:s0 ca
drwxrwxrwx. puppet puppet system_u:object_r:puppet_var_lib_t:s0 certificate_requests
drwxrwxrwx. puppet puppet system_u:object_r:puppet_var_lib_t:s0 certs
drwxrwxrwx. puppet puppet system_u:object_r:puppet_var_lib_t:s0 private
drwxrwxrwx. puppet puppet system_u:object_r:puppet_var_lib_t:s0 private_keys
drwxrwxrwx. puppet puppet system_u:object_r:puppet_var_lib_t:s0 public_keys
[root@server ssl]#
[root@server ssl]# pwd
/var/lib/puppet/ssl
[root@server ssl]#
```

I tried putting SELinux into passive mode and still am getting the same error.

Any Idea what it could be?

Comment: if `/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca` and all its ancestor directories are indeed readable / writable / searchable by the "puppet" user, and the puppetmaster runs as that user, and SELinux is not running in enforcing mode, then my best guesses are that either the host filesystem is mounted in read-only mode, or it is full or out of inodes, or it is a network filesystem that is subject to server-side access restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Let me check on that end.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the SSL directory or keep it renamed. Afterwards restart the puppet service and try again.